# Checking status of a logstash pipeline [no handler found for uri]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-api

I have an index that is not displaying any new data and uses a logstash pipeline. In order to check if the pipeline is running I ran the following: curl -XGET 'localhost:9600/_node/stats/pipelines?pretty'. I'm currently using elastic 8.x but I still got the error "no handler found for uri [/_node/stats/pipelines?pretty=true] and method [GET]". Is there perhaps another way to check if the logstash pipeline is working? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you run it? Hope that's a Logstash machine?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9600/_node/pipelines?pretty'`

Comment: I get "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_node/pipelines?pretty=&pretty=true] and method [GET], allowed: [POST]"

Comment: Are you trying to use this url on the node where elasticsearch is running? 
Is elasticsearch and logstash running on the same node?

This CURL is supposed to be used on the node where logstash is running.

Comment: What is the output of `curl localhost:9600` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error `no handler found for uri [/_node/stats/pipelines?pretty=true] and method [GET]` is an elasticsearch error. Is it possible that you by mistake connect to port 9200 instead of 9600 or your elasticsearch somehow runs on the port 9600 or something is forwarding traffic from port 9600 to elasticsearch?

Comment: I copy pasted the curl command into my dev tools console in kibana which trims the API down to GET /_node/stats/pipelines?pretty=true

Comment: Kibana console sends everything to elasticsearch. It doesn't communicate with Logstash. You need to use curl on the machine where Logstash is located.